# SQL Server soundex and MySQL soundex difference

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, soundex

Hello I want to use Soundex on SQL Server. I found good example for MySQL:

```
SELECT SOUNDEX('game of thrones')
```

When I tried this query:

- MySQL returns : G513652
- SQL Server returns : G500

I searched but couldn't find why. Aren't they same?

Comment: From MySQL: "This function, as currently implemented, is intended to work well with strings that are in the English language only. Strings in other languages may not produce reliable results. "

Comment: MySQL's `soundex` is more accurate and has additional precision.  You can use the default precision (4 chars) by using `substr`, like: `SELECT substr(SOUNDEX('game of thrones'),1,4);`

Comment: I need soundex for search query :/ I understood that not possible on mssql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex):

> A standard soundex string is four characters long, but the SOUNDEX() function returns an arbitrarily long string. You can use SUBSTRING() on the result to get a standard soundex string.

The version that MSSQL returns is the normal length, MySQL is just being different for some reason.

Also looks like MSSQL is only looking at the first word. With a third soundex implementation, `SOUNDEX('game')` gives `G500` and `SOUNDEX('game of thrones')` gives `G513`.